# List VMs and assigned GPUs

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I was wondering if it is possible to get a list with all the VMs in *Hyper V* and their assigned GPUs.

I have a server with 4 graphic cards and I split the cards in 2 or more virtual functions. So let's say GPU 1 is split in 2 virtual functions.
I have 2 VMs and I attach the new VFs to the VMs.
All good here except that I am unable to get a list to see what VFs are assigned to what VMs.
Do you guys know if it is possible to get this info? 
I used `Get-PnPdevice` to get the Instance Id of the graphic cards however there is nothing in VM properties that match that ID.

Thank you kindly

Comment: I don't have an environment to test this in but maybe this works: `Get-NetAdapterSriovVf`. Microsoft docs link: [Get-NetAdapterSriovVf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadaptersriovvf?view=win10-ps)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but according to the MS doc this cmdlet "Displays the SR-IOV virtual function settings for a network adapter." What I really need to find out is the VMs and assigned VFs.